# Passing Bags as input to a UDF

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to pass a tuple of bag to a UDF.

I have this data structure all of whose elements are a tuple (`arg`) of two bags (`x` and `y`):

```
data:{arg: (x: {(a: int,b: int,)},y: {(a: int,b: int)})}
```

Then, I wrote a UDF:

```
public class MyUDF extends EvalFunc<String> {

     public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
         if(input == null || input.size() == 0)
             return "empty";
         try{
            DataBag ref_regions = (DataBag)input.get(0);
            return "OK";
         }catch(Exception e){
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
             return null;
         }
     }
}
```

and I invoke it within a PigLatin script as follows:

```
res = foreach data generate MyUDF(arg);
```

Unfortunately I got this error:

```
org.apache.pig.data.BinSedesTuple cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.DataBag
```

which is printed by the `catch` statement.

Can you help me fixing that?

Comment: arg is not a bag but a tuple, therefore you get an exception

Answer (score 0):

What version of pig are you running?
This was an issue prior to 0.8.1 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1895
BinSedes is invoked usually when reading from a test file you create - I'd recommend changing Tuple input to a DataBag input in your UDF.